Why won't 24.04 install?
I'm using 22.04 on Desktop computer (Dell 3650) and three times over the past 3 weeks when window pops up and have clicked "Yes, install ..." but each time the installation appears as if it's starting but then nothing happens, and no messages to indicate status.  I also have Windows 7 as a dual boot option (but hardly used).  Any thoughts on why this is? Had thought of trying to install from website but haven't tried so far.

Are there any errors or suspect entries in your apt log? Run "less /var/log/apt/term.log" to view it.

Not sure if there are any errors or not. Have view of log on screenshot but won't attach here.

I can upload screenshot to 'post images' if that will work

FYI, I have software updates waiting to be downloaded but on clicking 'download' I get the messages: "unable to download updates:" and "The following packages have unmet dependencies:".  Presumably, those packages are the ones shown below these messages, a list of several pending updates.

I would install synaptic package manager with,  sudo apt-get install synaptic  -- Open synaptic and look at the left side-bar and choose 'custom filters' and you will see a new menu. Choose "Broken" and you should see the offending packages listed. There is also "Upgradable (upstream)" and "Missing Recommends"... One of these options should get you sorted out. Hope this helps.

Thanks. Sorry for delay in responding.

"Broken" lists nothing. "Missing Recommends" lists 18 items; there are no Installed Versions listed so presumably none of these are installed.  Should I install them all or only certain ones - in which case how do I select?  "Upgradable (Upstream)" lists many items all of which show installed and latest versions in respective columns.  Should I install all those items that show a Latest Version that is more advanced than the Installed Version?

Check to make sure your repositories are "checked". At the top menu-bar select 'Settings', select 'Repositories' from the menu and make sure all software sources are checked. (Also, look at 'Updates' while you're in that menu and change 'Notify me of a new Ubuntu version' to 'NEVER' to avoid that persistent pop-up.) If you did check any boxes, click 'Reload', then after it finishes checking for updates,  'Mark All Upgrades' and if there are updates, click 'Apply'. Otherwise, close Synaptic and open the terminal and enter -  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y  - Look for any warnings or notification prompts. This should bring your system up to date. P.S. Tried to post screenshot but it won't load.
